# ESP8266 noisy input when wires go through power supply

Tags: arduino, power-supply, esp8266, input, interference

I had made a circuit for an LED strip using an EDP12e. I had also attached two buttons to change between colors on the strip.

To make it compact I inserted the circuit board inside the casing of the 12V supply. It is a metal box with power circuit and some empty space where my circuit fits exactly. The LEDs work fine except the button inputs are throwing false positive signals when open (floating.)

I had connected a pull down resistor to the input pin. Below is the schematic I used:

[image: Schematic]

This is the actual circuit:

[image: Actual Circuit]

Please help me solve this issue.

Without passing those wires from supply didn't cause such noisy triggers but I kind of wanted to put my circuit inside the casing.

Comment: How do you expect the ESP8266 to function as a WiFi device when the whole thing including antenna is inside a metal box?  Or are you not using the radio functionality?

Comment: Actually top part is of plastic and esp's antenna is very close to that. I've a plan of extending antenna to outside of the box too.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: i build lots of ESP projects in metal "handy boxes", and they actually work just fine. Range might be shorter, but it's not been an issue for me.

Comment: this is why i (almost) always use INPUT_PULLUP for buttons; no need for external resistors, no interference from strays. You could try EMF blocking ferrite "beads", the black plastic collars you find on some USB cables and other signaling cables; they effectively prevent false PIR firings. Or use grounded+shielded cables to route the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noise is coupling onto the line, with enough current to create a voltage drop across your pulldown resistor.

The quickest fix would be to use a stronger (lower R) pulldown resistor.  R=1k would be much less likely to false trigger, and would only draw 11mW.

The next step would be to filter the noise, using a ferrite on the cable or adding an RC (watch the time constant) filter near the input.

[image: schematic]

This circuit has the following properties:

- No voltage divider: input will (eventually) reach full 3.3V
- C1 charges through R2: rises to 2.1V (63% of 3.3V) in 1 millisec (R2*C1)
- C1 discharges through R1+R2: drops 63% (3.3V to 1.2V) in 2 millisec ((R1+R2)*C1)

Comment: Lowering R helped a lot. Its not sensing false signals now. Although still on touching the input wires, causes false positives but its bearable. Thanks.

Comment: I can add detail for an RC filter if you're interested.

Comment: Yes please. I am just about to ask that. Thanks in advance.